# SQL Query Pattern Selecting

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table part

[image]

I need to select all from the rows where the first 7 characters of the Assoc.Ref column are the same on a specific day.

Result example

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need aggregation :

```
SELECT t.col
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.col
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you want exactly two rows for each then use `COUNT(*) = 2` instead .

If you want all rows then you can use windows function :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col) AS cnt
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE t.cnt > 1;
```

**EDIT :** After made update on question you might need `LEFT()` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(Date_created AS date), LEFT(associated_ref, 7)) AS cnt
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE t.cnt > 1 AND CAST(t.Date_created AS date) = '2019-02-08';
```

If the `Date_created` has no `time` then no conversation is needed. Just use `Date_created` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe I have put up the question the wrong way.

 

[Table](https://imgur.com/a/lrUfgYE)



I have a huge table similar to the one in the picture, and I need to select the rows where the first 7 character of a column matches, from a specific day.

Comment: @Bubbles_sharpest_guy_inthepark. . .  K. then use `LEFT(col, 7)` instead.

Comment: @Bubbles_sharpest_guy_inthepark. . .  BTW, your `table` destination is not aceesible to me so, you would need to update your question with sample data & desired result with text only.

Comment: @Bubbles_sharpest_guy_inthepark. . . Use `LEFT()` function in `PARTITION` clause, Check edited part.

Comment: Just one more question:

the database has over 4 million rows, with dates from 2004 until today. Is there a way I can select rows from only one day?

Comment: @Bubbles_sharpest_guy_inthepark. . .  If you want filter then use where clause `WHERE CAST(Date_created AS date) = '2019-02-08'`